# Replacing image resizer handler in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

In one of my web application I am using [ImageResizer.dll](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ImageResizer/) for resizing images. 
To resize the Image I just use **.ashx?width={any size}&height={any size}** that is working fine for me.

Here I am passing width and height in query string format but I don't want to use query string I want to know alternate option to resize my images.

Please suggest the option or also tell me this way is batter or not.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy solution but alternatively you can using text file for security purpose that read this file and getting width and height.Like that 
Width = 100;
Height = 100;

Answer (score 0):

use ASP image server control

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" />
```

//in the code behind

```
Image1.Width = 11;
Image1.Height = 11;
```